# Directshow, send with udp C#?

Tags: c#, directshow

Okay I am trying to find a way to send what is previewed.

But sadly, I don´t know how, as I need to get the buffer, or stream etc.

And I can´t find any information on it.
*Here is the code:*

```
public partial class Capture : Form
{
    private MemoryStream cap;
    private StreamWriter writecap;
    private UdpClient udpcap;
    private FileStream streamfile;

    public Capture()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        udpcap = new UdpClient();

        Filters filters = new Filters();
        DirectX.Capture.Capture capture = new DirectX.Capture.Capture(
            filters.VideoInputDevices[4],
            filters.AudioInputDevices[0]);

        panel2.Size = capture.FrameSize;  
        capture.PreviewWindow = panel2;

        capture.Cue();

        capture.Start();
    }
}
```

What I am doing is pretty much just showing the device in a Panel. What I want to do is send that preview through UDP.

I know how to save it as a file, but that´s it.

Comment: Consider using mpeg-ts for an multicast or unicast udp stream. That way it is compatible with other software like vlc which is handy for testing. But you will have to create a correct transport stream first which includes the compressed video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP datagrams are (a) limited in size (b) can be delivered out of order (c) no delivery guarantee. This makes conversations over UDP complicated and require that you reconsrtuct large frames from small datagrams, detect dropped packes and/or request resending, maintain lists of datagrams or receiving and possibly sending side as well. This makes UDP conversations larger than just a snippet of code.

For basics, check out these:

- [Sending and Receiving UDP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864999/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets)
- [Sending UDP Packet in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637697/sending-udp-packet-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I know that UDP is not the real way to go, but it work wonders for me in my situation, and i got no need to go to TCP for the moment.

But i am currently trying to do something, i have gotten a bit further, but it´s way unoptimized, will create a new thread as it´s different than this (not Directshow). And will let this be the answer of it, as my question is pretty off.