# C# Broadcast is UDP message, listen for multiple replies

Tags: c#, udp, broadcast, udpclient

I am trying to write some code that does a UDP broadcast, and then listens to replies from remote servers saying they exist. It's used to identify machines running a server app on the subnet so basically sends out a "who's there?" and listens for all the replies.

I have this in Java (works perfectly) where it sends a DatagramPacket broadcasting to a group address of 224.168.101.200. and then has a worker thread that keeps listening for incoming DatagramPackets coming in on the same socket.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832770/sending-udp-broadcast-receiving-multiple-messages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864999/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets) are not the answer as they say how to have the send and listen on different machines.

Comment: Whats the difference between different machines and on the same machine?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - to start, do I use the same UdpClient or distinct ones? Second, anything special I need to do if I send out the broadcast on a specific IP address?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but with two udpclient it will work. When broadcasting datagrams, both need to join the same multicast group.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I've tried both the same UdpClient and distinct ones - doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just made a working example for you, you could compare what went wrong. I created a windows forms applications with 2 textboxes and a button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _port = 28000;

    private string _multicastGroupAddress = "239.1.1.1";

    private UdpClient _sender;
    private UdpClient _receiver;

    private Thread _receiveThread;

    private void UpdateMessages(IPEndPoint sender, string message)
    {
        textBox1.Text += $"{sender} | {message}\r\n";
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _receiver = new UdpClient();
        _receiver.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(_multicastGroupAddress));
        _receiver.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port));

        _receiveThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                IPEndPoint sentBy = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);
                var dataGram = _receiver.Receive(ref sentBy);

                textBox1.BeginInvoke(
                    new Action<IPEndPoint, string>(UpdateMessages), 
                    sentBy, 
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataGram));
            }
        });
        _receiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        _receiveThread.Start();


        _sender = new UdpClient();
        _sender.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(_multicastGroupAddress));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox2.Text);
        _sender.Send(data, data.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, _port));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - I had 2 calls out of order and one call using the specific IP address. Once I changed those it worked.

Comment: It doesn't, (copied from my existed code) Multicast groups are useful when multiple senders are used. And you want to 'split' the senders/receivers to groups. In this case, it was already in my code @Alophind