# How can I Send and Receive JSON Message over UDP in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, udp

I am new at UDP and C#. I am just sending data as JSON format by UDP and receive data as JSON.

Sorry for my bad English. :|

Comment: Take a look at [this UDP-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864999/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets) and [this JSON-example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm). There are plenty of examples on how to use UDP with C# and also on how to handle JSON. From UDP you get (JSON-)strings (see examples) and from JSON-strings you can get objects via some JSON-library (see examples). Combine the two and you should be fine.

Comment: By the way your question is very broad and it would be nice to see some efforts which you've already made. Maybe the code you have up until now or the informations you know. We like to know exactly what you're stuck on not just "i need this, please help me". Good Luck!

Comment: If any mod or experienced poster sees this, should I make those two comments into an answer or what is the correct behaviour here? Also should I ask this question on meta or is this fine here (am still fairly new to so)?

Comment: @Joelius I think you are right. actually last three days I tried to solve this problem, but I didn't. Just now I solved the issue. 

I think you already know I'm totally new at stack overflow. That's why I made this mistake.

By the way thank you for everything :)

Comment: Glad you could solve it! Should I put my comments into an answer which you can accept?